# Drool syntax: rule not fire with ',' syntax but works with ' ,' (with an additional space before comma)

Tags: drools

I'm running into a weird issue that the drool rule does not give exceptions if the line ends in ',' but gives exception if there are additional space before comma (' ,'). Does anyone know why this is happening? The data comes from kafka and I'm expecting an exception printout. Is this related to how drool parse the argument? Thank you! Below are two examples.

```
//Case 1: not giving anything
when    
App(
        AppId == $inputId,
        source == "APP_STORE"
    )
then 
    System.out.println("Exception Caught!");

//Case 2: Can print out exception
    when    
    App(
            AppId == $inputId ,
            source == "APP_STORE"
        )
    then 
        System.out.println("Exception Caught!");
```

Comment: Where do you declare `$inputId`? Please show the full rule and an example input which will trigger one version but not the other.

Comment: Value of $inputId might have escape character '\\' at the end. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close the conversation, not sure if this is exclusive to my case.

But the issue got resolved after adding a space before the comma

AppId == $inputId ,

Comment: Problems caused by typos are off-topic; you can simply delete the question.